# Unordered Random Numbers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem. I'm trying to get 4 random numbers that will not be repeated and not ordered. For example (2,3,4,5) is not good, but (5,2,3,4) is ok.
We've implemented an algorithm but something's wrong with it.

```
   var needCreate = true;
    do
    {
        var lastIndex = int.MinValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            thisIndex = Random.Range(0, 5);
            UnorderedIndexes.Add(thisIndex);
            if (thisIndex < lastindex)
                needCreate = false;
            lastIndex = thisIndex;
        }
    }
    while (needCreate);
    foreach (int index in UnorderedIndexes)
        Debug.Log(index);
```

Comment: [System.Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: "something's wrong with it" What is?

Comment: If it is ordered then one could argue that it lost some 'randomness' thus less random than the original.

Comment: ok, I've solved the problem. I'm wrong in the code and that's why it did not work
Here: if (thisIndex < lastindex) => lastIndex & lastindex

Comment: bitwise and operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to generate random numbers in range without repeating, you can try this:

```
public static List<int> GenerateNumbers(int mn,int mx)
{
    List<int> source = new List<int>();
    for (int i = mn; i <= mx; i++)
        source.Add(i);
    var random = new Random();
    List<int> randomNumbers = new List<int>();
    while(source.Count != 0)
    {
        int randomIndex = random.Next(source.Count);
        randomNumbers.Add(source[randomIndex]);
        source.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
    }
    return randomNumbers;
}
```

usage example:

```
foreach (int x in GenerateRandomNumbers(2, 5))
        Console.WriteLine(x);
```

also you can seed it with your own list

Comment: thanks a lot #Diaa Eddin....but if I ask you again, because I was wrong in my condition. This method is super good, but what to do to avoid receiving a result like: 01234 or 02345